# 3.7V 1500Ah battery charging issue

Tags: batteries

i tried a little cct for charging mobile battery.....it consist of four 3.7V Li ion batteries,Voltage is controlled by 7805 regulator.....i got 4.91V at charging pin after diode ........mobile charging indicator blinks but battery doesn't got charged i.e  if battery is at 56% it remains there after an hour......

Practically i am learner in this field.......after troubleshooting i concluded that current isn't enough for charging.........

i found this forum quiet helpful for newbies and electronics hobbyists....

Help will be highly appreciated...........

[image: I got these cells from old laptop battery]

Answer (score 3):

1. This circuit is quite wasteful of the energy in your four 3.7 V batteries.  A buck converter would be much more appropriate here than a linear regulator.

   For 1 A out, your regulator would dissipate over 9 W.  That will require carefully designed cooling.  A buck converter would not only extend battery life significantly, but will be smaller and cheaper than this circuit after the heat dissipation issues are addressed.

   A 7805 isn't stable without a cap directly on its output, not thru a diode.  See its datasheet for the details.  There should also be a cap immediately on its input.  10 µF ceramic, not electrolytic, for both would be fine.

   I don't know what you think the diode is doing for you, but that's a bad place for one.  If you are afraid the battery might get below 5 V and you don't want power applied to the USB output (quite unlikely) to back drive the battery, put it directly in series with the battery.

   Note that the integral diode of a buck converter would take care of blocking reverse current without additional parts.

   Even if there was a reason for the diode, a Schottky would be more appropriate here.

Comment: thanks, actually purpose of four batteries is just to increase backup ..........

Comment: ........what i got from your sharing is that, this cct will not fulfill the purpose ........i want a cheap power bank using mentioned batteries( i have in plenty).....will you please share the right cct diagram for this? .....i mean buck converter.......or at least point out the direction where i can find one ........

Comment: @StarWars, please take some time and use a search engine to study the concept of buck regulator. What you will eventually want is a 5V buck regulator. Please do come back to this forum after you have learned a little bit more and ask additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

Charging circuit in mobile devices is a battery management controller in a logical hierarchy with main device CPU; depend how was implemented and what parameters is requested for charger (voltage range, some control line to activate/check chargin).
In your case is sensed a "charger" but maybe something is not ok and charging is not allowed...